# Selecting a Capacitor for Pulsed Power

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, pulse

Background:

I'm planning on making a hard tube modulated pulsed power supply. This will use a thyratron set to trigger at a frequency of 6 Hz, a 60 nF capacitor bank, and a 0.625 mH inductor.

The capacitor bank has a rise time (dV/dt) of 2,879 V/uS and is charged with 10 kV DC.

Question 1: What will the peak current be?

Question 2: Will the energy of each pulse be around 3 J? This assumes that 0.5CV^2 can be used to predict the approximate energy of each pulse.

Comment: This sound like homework? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you know about the current through a capacitor? How is it related to the change in the voltage across the capacitor?

Comment: @MadHatter No, this is just a personal project of mine. I can understand the resemblance though. I'm just trying to figure out if the peak current coming out of my capacitor will follow C(dV/dt) or 0.5CV. Thank you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My understanding was that i=C(dV/dt), but that the energy of a pulse can also be determined by 0.5CV^2. However, my understanding of each would seem to contradict itself.

Comment: Energy and current are completely different quantities. You have one formula for current that does not depend on energy, and you have another formula for energy that does not depend on current. What exactly is your confusion here?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson If I divide the peak pulse energy (0.5*C*V^2) by the voltage, the current is nowhere close to the quantity that would be found with the CdV/dt equation.

Comment: You can't divide the energy by the voltage and get current. Maybe you need to investigate the difference between energy and power.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think I might not have explained myself well. Since each pulse lasts 10 uS, I was planning to divide the amount of energy per pulse (determined by 0.5CV^2) by 10^-5, this would yield the power in watts (J/s). This value would then be divided by the voltage of the pulse to get the peak current of the pulse. Would this be an accurate way to predict the absolute maximum current of the pulse? Thank you.

Comment: If you divide the total energy by the total amount of time needed to deliver that energy, then what you will get is **average** power. However, the voltage **across the capacitor** is not constant during that time, and is not in phase with the current. The best you could hope for from this approach (working from the energy) would be an **average** current, not a **peak** current. One should be able to come up with the differential equations for voltage and current, but I would just put together a simulation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thank you for the advice, do you know of any software/simulation tools that are particularly good for this? Thanks again

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Also, I heard that PFNs (where only an inductor, capacitor, and switching device are used) tend to half the input voltage (the pulse has half the voltage of the charging voltage applied to the capacitor). If this is so, should I used half of the charging voltage for the 0.5CV^2 equation? Thank you.